# Editing Color Mode of EPS or Illustrator files using C#

Tags: c#

In my Winform application i am loading an EPS file to the Illustrator, now i want to edit the color mode and color profile of that file through C# code, how can i code for this, Please help, Please provide any example code...

I upload the file to the Illustrator as follows but doesn't knows how to change the color mode and Color Profile Please help me..

```
AppIllustrator = new Illustrator.Application();

Illustrator.Document illuDoc = AppIllustrator.Open(EPSFile,                      
Illustrator.AiDocumentColorSpace.aiDocumentRGBColor, null);
```